# How could impersonate in kerberos?

Tags: security, kerberos, impersonation, delegation

I have an user Jake, and two Server A and B in a kerberos realm, after Jake authenticates to Server A, I want Server A impersonates Jake to connect Server B and do something.

My question is how could I configure or implement Server A to impersonate the user who has been authenticated and connected to it?

Any advice is appreciate!

Comment: This is not on-topic here, and is too broad to be on-topic at SU or SF.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is [Kerberos Constrained Delegation](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/feature/Advanced-Kerberos-topics-Delegation-of-authentication). I have an example working for a java Spring Boot application using spring security kerberos (with a few tweaks) and Active Directory [here](https://github.com/tellisnz/collared-kerberos).